# The best way to make a 2D animated character?

Tags: javascript, c++, animation, 2d, character

I have a question. I want to make a 2d animated character. I don't want to do a game but I need this character in my windows desktop, then I will press a button and the character must do a action. I don't know if I must use a game engine for this project, or only with c++ with a framework as wxwidget or Qt, or maybe use web technologies (css and javascript) and a framework for run it in desktop. What do you think I should use for this project?

Comment: One issue with this question is that "best way" and "what do you think" are subjective and opinionated; there is no single correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Animation is performed by:

1. Drawing sprite/bitmap at location.
2. Delay
3. Erase sprite/bitmap.
4. Draw at a new location.
5. Repeat at step 2.

On Windows platforms, there are functions for drawing 2d bitmaps on the screen.  You will need to search the MSDN site to find them.

Another alternative, is to create a window with the character.  The window would have an "invisible" border.  You would need to draw the character in the window, then position the window.  Modify the character, draw, refresh the window and move the window.  There are API for drawing on windows and positioning them.  There are frameworks which can assist you with drawing windows and drawing on them.

Comment: My recommendation is to use a language that can either interface with the Windows API or has high level constructs for playing with graphs and hides the underlying implementation.